# Add / Remove HTML element from page in directive

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have a directive that shows or hides an HTML element [StackBlitz][1] :

```
<div *authorize="12">{{user.name}}</div>
```

And the Authorize directive is:

```
export class AuthorizeDirective implements OnInit {

  id: number;

  @Input() set authorize(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private element: ElementRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { 

    this.authorizationService.authorize(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      if (result == true)
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
      else 
        this.viewContainer.clear();
    });    

  }

}
```

As expected this adds the `DIV` to the page when `result` is `true`.

But when `authorize` method updates and returns a new `value` and `result` is `true` the `DIV` is added again.

When the value returned by `authorize` is updated I would like to:

```
if (value == false)
  // Remove DIV if exists in page
if (value == true)
  // Add DIV if does not exist in page
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `this.viewContainer.clear()`?

Comment: Seems to me your best bet is to maintain state in your directive, then compare the value of the subscribable to your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [distinctUntilChanged()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) so that the observable does not emit duplicate values.

```js
    this.authorizationService.authorize(this.id).pipe(
       distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe(result => {
      if (result == true)
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
      else 
        this.viewContainer.clear();
    });
```